# Quicksort a list and convert it into list of tuples (elem, count)

Tags: haskell, quicksort

How would I convert a list of unsorted words into list of tuples (word, count), sorted by words (fst) min-max case-insensitive?

```
["AAA","America", "England", "Spain"," Ireland"," aeroplane",
 "aeroplane", "Aeroplane", "AeRoPlAne", "helicopter", "HELICOPTER",
 "Zebra", "America", "Elephant", "abc", "A.B.C." , "haskell", "Haskell", "ZZZ", "zzz"]
```

Expected outputs:

```
[("a.b.c.",1),("aaa",1),("abc",1),("aeroplane",4),("america",2),("elephant",1)
,("england",1),("haskell",2),("helicopter",2),("ireland",1),("spain",1),("zebra",1),("zzz",2)]

[("a.b.c",1), ("zzz", 2)]
```

Comment: Show us the code and the exact error.

Comment: @DanielWagner:  Sir, Kindly visit my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261974/complete-set-of-indentation-rules-in-haskell It has all the details you might need to understand the exact error at my end.

Comment: @Optimight It was unclear if you meant min-max word or count. Please correct anything I've lost in my edits.

Comment: I wanted to bifurcate each unique word and its number of occurrence in the list. e.g. (aeroplane, 4) . one word one tuple with its occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've broken this down into steps that should make this easier to grasp. First, sort the list, then reduce it into a list of (Word, Count) tuples.

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =
  (quicksort [a|a<-xs, a<=x]) ++ [x] ++ (quicksort [a|a<-xs, a>x])

addCount :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
addCount a [] = [(a, 1)]
addCount a (x:xs)
  | a == fst x = (fst x, (snd x) + 1) : xs
  | otherwise  = x : (addCount a xs)

occurrences :: [(String, Int)] -> [String] -> [(String, Int)]
occurrences counts [] = counts
occurrences counts (x:xs) =
  occurrences countL xs
  where countL = addCount x counts

myList = ["AAA","America", "England", "Spain","Ireland", "aeroplane",
          "aeroplane", "Aeroplane", "AeRoPlAne", "helicopter", "HELICOPTER",
          "Zebra", "America", "Elephant", "abc", "A.B.C." , "haskell", "Haskell",
          "ZZZ", "zzz"]

main = do
  let downcased = map (map toLower) myList
  let sorted = quicksort downcased
  let occurencesL = occurrences [] sorted
  putStrLn . show $ occurencesL
  putStrLn . show $ [head occurencesL, last occurencesL]
```

This is *very* verbose but, I'm hoping you have an easier time understanding what is happening this way.

An example of a shorter way:

```
  import Data.Char (toLower)
  import Data.List

  main = do
    let l = map (\a -> (head a, length a)) $ groupBy (\x y -> (map toLower x) == (map toLower y)) myList
    putStrLn . show $ l
    putStrLn . show $ [head l, last l]
```

Comment: Great thanks for your input. I am a haskell beginner and going through learn-you-a-haskell. Don't know how to run main?  Please guide. I ran quicksort and it works but the result for occurrence part don't know how to get it?

Comment: You should put this in a file ending in 'hs', say "Sort.hs". The easiest way to run a single file is to use the 'runghc' or 'runhaskell' commands eg. `runghc Sort.hs` on my Mac. This is the same on Linux but, I'm unsure about Windows.

You can also run it from GHCI; load the file with ':l Sort' the run 'main'.

Comment: I definitely will like to see the most concise code. I don't find any difficulty in reading and understanding the code so far. My problem was I was getting parse error due to some indentation issue in my code or and editor tool issue or something (weird).

Comment: yes, Sorry to bother you. I ran the main command from WinGHCi interface. Got the result successfully. Can you please show me the concisest code for the same process?

Comment: I ran the code. You need to see this: "ghci>" "aeroplane" `compare` "abc"
GT
it :: Ordering
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
"ghci>" "aeroplane" `compare` "aaa"
GT
it :: Ordering
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
"ghci>" "aaa" `compare` "abc"
LT
it :: Ordering
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
Something wrong in comparision.

Comment: @Optimight I've added a one liner. With a little effort I'm certain you could do better.

Comment: @Optimight Those examples of `compare` usage are correct. If you don't understand, please make a question about it.

Comment: I ran the one liner in separate file. And getting this error: "ghci>" :l sortToTupleConcise

sortToTupleConcise.hs:4:3: parse error on input `main'
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sortToTupleConcise.hs, interpreted )
Failed, modules loaded: none.
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)

Comment: I'm unsure what that would be without looking at your code. My example works if you copy it carefully. Start from there. Otherwise, this is becoming a long discussion of some unrelated issues, I don't really have the time to continue. Please mark this answered if you think my answer is correct (or not.) Hope I was able to help.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use `group . map toLower` instead of `groupBy (\x y -> (map toLower x) == (map toLower y`))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner:

```
    Data.List.sort $ Data.Map.toList $ Data.Map.fromListWith (+) [(map Data.Char.toLower word, 1) | word <- lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

The grouping function:

```
myGroup :: [[Char]] -> [([Char],Int)]
myGroup = fmap (\x -> (head x,length x)) . groupBy (==) . sort . fmap (fmap toLower . filter (not . isSpace))
```

Note that I assume you want to remove spaces from String. You can easily change that part by changing the filter.

Then the boundaries function:

```
headLast :: [t] -> [t]
headLast xs = [head xs,last xs]
```

Comment: I want to count the occurrence of a particular word in the list irrespective of its font case.